# How to change windows win key + w shortcut without Autohotkey?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, windows-11, windows-key

I want to press "windows + w" and it opens a specific folder.

I don't want to use third parties softwares.

I want to replicate "windows + e" but with "windows + w"

I've tried to create a shortcut for the folder and use Power Toys to redirect the shortcut "windows + w" to "ctrl + shift + alt + w", but it's too slow.

There is probably a registry solution for this...